# How to declare parameters in decode url to send them with header?

Tags: jquery, node.js, url, parameters, decode

I have this decode url: `https://api/a/?page=1&q[sort]=name ASC`

I want to remove `page` and `sort` from url and send them as a params:

```
    params:{
      page: page,
     q['sort']='name ASC'
    }
```

It works for `page`, but with `sort` I get an error, because I'don't know how to declare it: `q[sort]=name ASC`
In my url api `sort` is declate as: q[sort] string. I use node js.

Comment: This depends on your exact use case, but try `"q['sort']": 'name ASC'`

Comment: The paramter have to be JSON valid. so try `params: { page: page, q: { sort: 'name ASC' }}`

Comment: @DerHerrGammler It doesn't work, but solution from comment above works: `"q['sort']": 'name ASC'`. But is it possible to change this string to object to be JSON valid?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan thank you, it works, but is it possible to change this string into object to be JSON valid?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean as that already can be converted to JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution thanks to @Rory McCrossan : `"q['sort']": 'name ASC'`